# How to set workbench to not create fields automatically when add foreign keys

Tags: entity-relationship, mysql-workbench, workbench

Workbench automatically adding new columns to table when I'm creating foreign keys. I need manualy choose columns, because I have columns and not need to add again.

For 1:n is tool "Relations using existing colums", but I also need relations for 1:1, n:m not auto add new columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons for 1:1 etc exist only for convenience. It doesn't matter how you create the relationship you can always double click it to open the relationship editor and change the properties to any cardinality, switch on identifying relationship or make it mandatory.